# Spaces in name of local file are replaced with zeroes when opened in browser

Tags: batch-file, browser, whitespace, local-files

I have a .bat file that opens a local file in a browser.  The path to the local file contains spaces (not by my choice):

`file:///N:/Users/Firstname%20Lastname/Placeholder%20Report%20Name.html`

However, the browser changes this to:

`file:///N:/Users/Firstname0Lastname/Placeholder0Report0Name.html`

The `%20` is replaced with `0` instead of , so the link does not work.

I've tried replacing `file:///` with `file:\\` and a different browser, but the result is the same.  What am I missing?  I can't change the name or path of the target file.

Comment: The `%` sign has special meaning in batch files. You need to double it (escaping), so `file:///N:/Users/Firstname%20Lastname/Placeholder%20Report%20Name.html` must be `file:///N:/Users/Firstname%%20Lastname/Placeholder%%20Report%%20Name.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `%` with another one like this:

```
file:///N:/Users/Firstname%20Lastname/Placeholder%20Report%20Name.html
```

->

```
file:///N:/Users/Firstname%%20Lastname/Placeholder%%20Report%%20Name.html
```

Reason for that is the fact that `%2` stands for the second argument, that got send to the batch file:

```
yourBat.bat first second
```

would result in your browser path beeing

```
file:///N:/Users/Firstnamesecond0Lastname/Placeholdersecond0Reportsecond0Name.html
```

as `%2` gets substituted with the word second.

With another `%` added this will be escaped.